# Borders in Bootstrap wrap around the row instead of the element I am applying the border to?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when I add a border to my `<h3>` tag it wraps around the row instead of the actual element inside it. I have tried various changes of the HTML structure and CSS however I am unable to find a solution.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="brand col-md-5"><img src="media/img/logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales"       class="img-rounded logo-custom"></div>
    <h3 class="phone-number col-md-7">01429 7654287</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.phone-number {
text-align: right;
margin-top: 2.8em;
diaplay: inline-block;
border: 1px solid orange;
```

As you can see the text aligns right as I need the number to display right of the page.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `h3` with a `div` with the class `col-md-7`.

The `col-md-7` class is used for a column and in most cases, you don't really apply it directly to elements like a header tag.

Answer (score 1):

almost good, change

```
diaplay: inline-block;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
```